# Design, repeated code - need some advice

Tags: php, architecture

I'll try to explain my situation as clear as I can.

I'm building a framework. Its system contains following directories:
1) Core - routing, main class (autoloading, configs, constants), requests
2) Helpers
3) Libraries

In index.php, I set all most important configuration variables such as the base url, or index file. I set them inside of the "main class".

These attributes are private, because I dont want anyone to change them during the request flow.

So the only point of access to these variables is from the "main class" methods.

---

Now, one of these private variables is `$_base_url`.

I want users to be able to access base_url from some better place however, like URL class (inside of the helper directory).

---

To achieve this, I have to create two methods - get_base_url() inside of the "main class", and get_base_url() inside of the url class, which will do something like this:

```
class Url {

   public static function get_base_url() {
      return Main_Class::get_base_url();
   }

}
```

My problem is - I have a couple of such variables which I'd like to call from different classes.

I will have a lot of repeated code.

The only solution I see is just setting these variables in different classes directly, but I'd like to have them centralized inside the main class.

How should I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another class called variables (or whatever you prefer) then use static variables with that clase to be able to call them back and forth.  Something like this:

```
<?php class Variables {
  static $_base_url = "http://base_url";
} ?>
```

That way you can call your variables like this:

`Variables::$_base_url;`

**To expand on your comment:**

With inheritance you can have a situation where 2 classes have different values for the same $variable. In this example all instances will hold a different value for $_base_url;

```
class ParentClass {
  protected $_base_url = "SOME VALUE";
}

class SubClassA extends ParentClass {

  protected __construct() {
    $this->_base_url = 'VALUE X';
  }
}

class SubClassB extends ParentClass {

  protected __construct() {
    $this->_base_url = 'DIFFERENT VALUE THAN SubClassA';
   }
}
```

Again, it depends on what you are trying to accomplish. If you want your variables act more like Settings or if you just want to have those variables within your instance.

Comment: Uh, inheritance vs centralized class for variables...is one of them better here than the other in my situation, or should I just flip a coin? :P

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do. Inheritance will allow you to have a different value for each instance. Centralized variable class will ensure that no matter what object is accessing the variable it will only have one value.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need a variable to be called from the classname, if the classes extends your MainClass then use parent::get_base_url();

Comment: Classes don't extend MainClass. That could solve my problem, but I couldn't see connection between helpers/library and the main class, so there's no any inheritance.